# Charge Balance and power law?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, aqueous-solution

I've come across a statement in a paper* that's poorly explained, and I can't work out the reasoning behind it. I suspect this is embarrassingly basic, but could anyone please explain the theory behind the following (from the bottom of the second paragraph of the discussion)?

> For a reaction involving B(OH)<sub>4</sub><sup>-</sup> and CO<sub>3</sub><sup>2-</sup>, a B(OH)<sub>4</sub><sup>-</sup> can balance the charge of only 1/2 a CO<sub>3</sub><sup>2-</sup>, thus a dependence *[of the B/Ca ratio in synthetic aragonite]* on [B(OH)<sub>4</sub><sup>-</sup>]/[CO<sub>3</sub><sup>2-</sup>]<sup>0.5</sup> would be expected.

I'm unsure why a power law applies here.

* Holcomb, M.; DeCarlo, T. M.; Gaetani, G. A.; McCulloch, M. Factors affecting B/Ca ratios in synthetic aragonite. *Chem. Geol.* **2016,** *437,* 67–76. [DOI: 10.1016/j.chemgeo.2016.05.007](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.chemgeo.2016.05.007).

Comment: Your quoted statement would make sense in discussing the dependence of the equilibrium constant of a reaction involving $2\ce{B(OH)_4^-}$ on one side and $\ce{CO_3^{2-}}$ on the other, but I'm unsure if this is relevant.

Comment: Thanks @a-cyclohexane-molecule. Could you point me towards some reading so I can understand *why* this is this case?

Comment: I don't have a good resource on hand, but a Google search regarding *equilibrium constant* should be productive. Essentially, we define the equilibrium constant for the reaction $\ce{aA + bB \to cC + dD}$ as $$K = \frac{[A]^a[B]^b}{[C]^c[D]^d}.$$ Specializing to this reaction indeed shows the desired proportionality.

Again, do note that I'm not certain that this is what the authors of the paper are getting at.

Comment: I think you're exactly right. They discuss the stoichiometry of the reaction as $B(OH)_4 + 0.5 CO_3^{2-}$, so this makes sense. Thanks for the pointer!